# String или StringBuilder (использование)

Tags: java, строки

Когда нужно использовать String  и когда нужно использовать StringBuilder?
Какие отличия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максим,

**String**

Это immutable объект, что значит если Вы единожды его создали изменить объект (именно объект, а не ссылку на него) Вы уже не сможете. Каждый `String` объект помещается в *Constant String Pool*, на объекты которого, по сути, движок может устанавливать несколько ссылок.
И поскольку `String` immutable, следовательно он потокобезопасен.

**StringBuilder**

В отличие от `String` является mutable, что означает что само состояние объекта может меняться. Часто, говоря о `StringBuilder` следует упомянуть и о `StringBuffer`. Оба класса имеют одинаковые методы, вот только в `StringBuffer` все методы синхронизированы, что делает его потокобезопасным (ровно как и String). `StringBuilder` в свою очередь является не потокобезопасным. Однако плата за потокобезопасность - производительность. Синхронизированные методы работают медленнее, поэтому `StringBuilder` будет работать быстрее, чем `StringBuffer`.

Иными словами:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
String c = "a" + "b"
```

В результате этого кода будет создано 3 объекта: "a", "b" и "ab".

Но если переписать тоже самое, используя `StringBuilder`, будет создан всего один объект "ab" (минуя создание промежуточных "a" и "b").

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("a");
builder.append("b");
```

Надеюсь мой ответ Вам что-то да прояснил.

Answer (score 1):

Полезные ресурсы :

http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/string-stringbuffer-difference

https://bunkerbook.ru/uroki-po-java/raznitsa-mezhdu-string-i-stringbuffer-stringbuilder-v-Java/

https://o7planning.org/ru/10217/java-string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder-tutorial

При работе с текстовым данными, Java предоставляет вам 3 класса String, StringBuffer и StringBuilder.

Класс String является immutable - Вы не можете модифицировать объект String, но можете заменить его созданием нового экземпляра. Создание нового экземпляра обходится дороговато.От этого класса нельзя унаследоваться.Может использоваться для регистрации, ауетентификиции в приложении. У String создается строковый пул, благодаря тому, что строка - неизменима. Отличный кандидат для ключа в Map, так как ее Hashcode кэшируется в момент создания. Так же строки исползуются в java classloader и благодаря своей неизменности - обеспечивает правильность загрузки класса при помощи Classloader .

Класс StringBuffer является mutable - использовать StringBuffer или StringBuilder следует тогда, когда вы хотите модифицировать содержимое. StringBuilder был добавлен в пятой джаве и он во всем идентичен классу StringBuffer, за исключением того, что он не синхронизирован, что делает его значительно шустрее. Но цена скорости - небезопасное поведение в мультипоточной среде.

Comment: ответ должен содержать не ссылки, а решение вопроса прямо в ответе.

Comment: @pavlofff, обновил ответ )